# Django queryset to find a char value with filtered out spaces?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

There are database string values that are sometimes stored with unnecessary spaces:
"SDF@#$#@  132423"

Given the value without spaces in the UI of a program:
"SDF@#$#@132423"

How could I do a Django queryset filter to find the Database value (with spaces) from the UI input value sans spaces?

Answer (score 3):

A way is to add another field to your model to store "cleaned" values.
Next you only have to search for the "cleaned" user entry in this field.